# Aggression performance with formulas

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a difference in the performance of Formula1 vs Formula2?

How would I go about testing the performance of Formula1 vs Formula2?

```
SELECT SomeGroupedInfo
 , SUM(Dollars) - SUM(DollarsAdjustments) Formula1
 , SUM(Dollars - DollarsAdjustments) Formula2
FROM LargeTable_50MillRecords
GROUP BY SomeGroupedInfo
```

NOTE: The Dev environment does not have 50 million records but production will

Comment: Did you run both (each one as a single query) and compare them?

Comment: I don't have that much data at this point. The lead is only providing a small sample of data.

Comment: Your SQL implies you have 50Million rows, @Jmyster.

Comment: It will, I'm just trying to find out if there is a performance difference in the way I'm writing the SQL

Comment: There shouldn't be a performance diff.  The optimizer is smart enough to sort it out.  OTOH, why not generate some data (use one of the many free/trial tools out there)? then test with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments run both aggregation methods as separate queries and look at query stats (following query help for that):

```
SELECT  t.[text] as sql_Text, 
        s.total_elapsed_time, 
        ((s.total_elapsed_time + 0.0) /s.execution_count) as avg_elapsed_time,
        s.total_worker_time, 
        ((s.total_worker_time + 0.0) / s.execution_count) as avg_worker_time,
        s.total_clr_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s 
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(s.[sql_handle]) AS t
WHERE t.[text] LIKE N'%LargeTable_50MillRecords%'
ORDER BY s.last_execution_time;
```

You could also have valuable insights by setting `SET STATISTICS IO ON;` just before executing `select` queries, this will give you IO load i.e. how many pages SQL engine had to read to get the result for each query, this info available at message section of query result.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a way to get statistics on it. I will have to try this on my local machine where I can create a 50 million record table and test

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run each formula and see how much time it takes.

```
SELECT SomeGroupedInfo
 , SUM(Dollars) - SUM(DollarsAdjustments) Formula1
FROM LargeTable_50MillRecords
GROUP BY SomeGroupedInfo
```

and

```
SELECT SomeGroupedInfo
 , SUM(Dollars - DollarsAdjustments) Formula2
FROM LargeTable_50MillRecords
GROUP BY SomeGroupedInfo
```

The one who takes the lowest time would be the most efficient.

Comment: First, how that is answering the question? Second, both of your queries (1 and 2) are the same.

Comment: That was an error, the queries are now different according to the two query. The answer is run the SELECT separately and observe the time differences to be able to tell if there's a performance difference.